# difference between these two kde plots?

Tags: python, statistics, seaborn, data-science

i am new to EDA and i was trying analyse a HABERMAN dataset. and i found multiple ways to plot a KDE plot. when i tried them for the same input i am getting a kinda different graph. can u please explain me the diffece btwn the two plotting methods.
Method 1:

```
sns.kdeplot(data=HAB, x="age",hue="status",shade=True,multiple="stack",palette="flare"
```

[image: output of method 1]

Method 2:

```
sns.FacetGrid(HAB,hue="status",height = 5)\
.map(sns.distplot,"age")\
. add_legend();
```

OUTPUT:
[image: 2]

Comment: the first histogram is stacked... means the y-axis value is cumulative..

Comment: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html has some examples comparing different `multiple=...` options.